# Google Spreadsheet Tracking Times

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

My goal here is to take a date, convert it to milliseconds, add 14 days to the date, and convert it back to a readable date instead of milliseconds. Here is my code:

```
var startDate = new Date("January 13, 2017 00:00:00");
var endDate = new Date ("January 26, 2017 23:59:59");
var startDateInMilliSeconds = startDate.getTime();
startDate = startDateInMilliSeconds + 86400000 * 14;

date = startDate.toUTCString();
Logger.log(date);
```

However, each time I run it, I get this error: "Cannot find function toUTCString in object 1485504000000". toUTCString works in every online example I have found, I don't know why it doesn't work here. Can someone help?

Comment: tracker is not defined outside of the function. Variables only exist in their functions.

Comment: you have COMPLETELY changed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why toUTCString() is not working, but add this in your code and you will get a new date with 14 days added.

```
var startDate = new Date("January 13, 2017 00:00:00");
var endDate = new Date ("January 26, 2017 23:59:59");
var startDateInMilliSeconds = startDate.getTime();
startDate = startDateInMilliSeconds + 86400000 * 14;

//date = startDate.toUTCString();
var finalDate = new Date(startDate);
Logger.log(finalDate);
```

You just forgot to convert time's milisecond representation to Date() object.